# FSM for email address format validation

Tags: regex, validation, fsm, state-machine

Have come up with the following [Finite State Machine](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~eberlein/cs337/Project3.pdf) for validating an email based on the following pattern. Is this valid to be able to validate an emailaddress format (more specifically, is the FSM a correct translation of the regex below)?

[image]

Further, even when valid, the stages S4 and S5 can be removed (repeating states) and instead S1 can be an accepting state?

Email address format example: `abc23ss@1domain.ext`

Regex as a base for drawing the FSM: `[a-z0-9]+@[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: Oh and no, this will not match my email address. It has a period before the @. In times gone by, it even had two periods in the domain part.

Comment: Are you asking if this regexp is correct for validating email, or are you asking if the FSM is a correct translation of the regexp you gave?

Comment: Why do you need to create your own FSM? If you use a regexp engine it will do that for you.

Comment: @Barmar Updated the question to be more clear. I am asking if the FSM is a correct translation of the regex i gave. Also, I am trying to gain more understanding of the FSMs and hence creating on my own.

Comment: Maybe this question is more appropriate for cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that does seems more appropriate and I should have posted there.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more appropriate for cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: `abc@com` is a valid email address, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's not a bad starting point, but it's not quite there yet, and you will have to revise your FSM quite a bit. For example, the following email address would be invalid according to your FSM:

```
some-thing.someone@somewhere.co.uk
```

Comment: Agreed, it does not handle all possible email addressess but was looking for the confirmation of this 'first draft'.